# Error in simplest Gtk::Builder get_widget() prog

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, builder

This is my program:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
Gtk::Main gtkmain(argc, argv);

Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Builder> builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("practice_1_builder.glade");

Gtk::Window win;
builder->get_widget("winobj", win);
Gtk::Main::run(win);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I use this command in terminal to compile it, as I use for any other GTK+ program I can correctly compile:

```
g++ myprog.cpp -o myprog `dpkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`
```

And I get this error:

```
builder_0.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
builder_0.cpp:10:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘Gtk::Builder::get_widget(const char [7], Gtk::Window&)’
builder_0.cpp:10:35: note: candidate is:
/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm/builder.h:435:8: note: template<class T_Widget> void    Gtk::Builder::get_widget(const Glib::ustring&, T_Widget*&)
```

I tried many twiddles, defining `win` as pointer, converting the string literal to `Glib::ustring`, ..., but didn't work.
Appreciating helps! :-)

Comment: What error did you get when you defined `win` as pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is very clear to me. T_Widget*& means, that you have to pass a (reference to a ) pointer. I changed your code to this:

```
Gtk::Window *win;
builder->get_widget("winobj", win);
Gtk::Main::run(*win);
```

Now it should work as expected.

Comment: OMG! It works! And I can't believe my failure all these times was forgetting the dereferencing in `run()` and I ignorantly didn't even notice!
Thanks so much for your help ipc :-)